# How do I set the background of an svg using Snap svg and then add text on top of it?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am trying to create an svg that has an image as the background. I would then like to add some text in the foreground in the center of the svg (e.g. "my text here"). However, I cannot even figure out how to set the background to be the image. When I try to do it the entire svg disappears. My code:

```
var width = 250;
var height = 275;

var s = Snap("#svg").attr({
  width: width,
  height: height
})

var img = card.image('https://i.imgur.com/LQIsf.jpg', 0, 0, 250, 275)
var p = img.toPattern(0, 0, 250, 275);

var card = s.rect(0, 0, width, height, 10).attr({
  //fill: "#f3f3f3",
  stroke: "#000",
  strokeWidth: 1,
  fill: p,
});
```

[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0szm6fk/1/)

After I get that, how do I then add the text in the center of the svg?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be `s.image(...`, not `card.image(...`

Comment: Indeed. How do you overlay text on top of it, though? https://jsfiddle.net/nzfsgdjw/

Comment: `s.text(25, 100, "Hello!").attr({ 'font-size': 80, fill: 'yellow' });`